# How to update user status using button without update all parameters in laravel

Tags: laravel

i want to update status user just pass parameter of 'status'.
this is my code, but i don't know, why i can not update user status. how to fix this problem?

my controller

```
public function activation()
{
    // dd('test');
    $action = Input::get('status');
    if (Input::get('activate'))
    {
        $this->activateUser($action);
    }
    elseif (Input::get('inactivate'))
    {
        $this->deactivateUser($action);
    }
    return redirect(route('admins-users.index'))->with('message-post', 'Status was updated successfully');
}

public function activateUser($user)
{
    //dd('active');
    User::findOrNew($user)->update(['status' => "1"]);
}

public function deactivateUser($user)
{
    // dd('nonactive');
    User::findOrNew($user)->update(['status' => "0"]);
}
```

my route

```
Route::post('admins-users/status', 'Backend\StatusController@activation');
```

my view

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'admins-users/status')) !!}
       @if ($user->status)
          {!! Form::submit('inactivate', ['name' => 'inactivate', 'class'=>'btn btn-xs btn-default']) !!}
       @else
          {!! Form::submit('Activate', ['name' => 'activate', 'class'=>'btn btn-xs btn-success']) !!}
       @endif
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several ways. finally, i was found the answer for this problem using Ajax and select option. i add hash id before pass to controller and decode again in controller. i thinks id that pass must be concerned.

my controller

```
public function control(Request $request){
    $status = $request->status;
    $iduser = $request->iduser;
    $key = Hashids::connection('main')->decode($iduser)[0] ??  abort(404);
    $update = User::where('id', $key)->update(['status'=> $status]);
    if($update)
    {
        return redirect(route('admins-users.index'))->with('message-post', 'Status user was updated successfully');
    }
}
```

my form
using hash id to encode id user

```
 @php $parameter = Hashids::connection('main')->encode($user->id); @endphp
{!! Form::hidden(null,$parameter, ['id'=> 'iduser'.$parameter ])!!}
{!! Form::select(
                'status',
                array(1=>'Active',0=>'Not Active'),
                $user->exists ? $user->status : null,
                [
                    'id'          => 'action'.$parameter,
                    'placeholder' => 'Choose a status'
                ]
            )
!!}
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    @foreach($users as $user)
    @php $parameter = Hashids::connection('main')->encode($user->id); @endphp
    $("#action{{ $parameter }}").change(function(){
        var status = $("#action{{ $parameter }}").val();
        var iduser = $("#iduser{{ $parameter }}").val();
        if(status==""){
            alert("Please select an option");
        }
        else{
            if (confirm('Do you want to change {{ $user->name }} status to {{ $user->status ? 'InActive' : 'Active' }}?')) {
                $.ajax({
                url: '{{ url("/action") }}',
                data: 'status=' + status + '&iduser=' + iduser,
                type: 'get',
                success:function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                }
                });
                document.location.reload();
            }
        }
    });
    @endforeach
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
  {!! Form::open(['url' => 'admins-users/status', 'method' => 'get' !!}
   <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ $user->id }}">
   @if ($user->status)
      {!! Form::submit('inactivate', ['name' => 'inactivate', 'class'=>'btn btn-xs btn-default']) !!}
   @else
      {!! Form::submit('Activate', ['name' => 'activate', 'class'=>'btn btn-xs btn-success']) !!}
   @endif
  {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Your route

```
Route::get('admins-users/status', 'Backend\StatusController@activation');
```

Your Controller Method

```
public function activation(Request $request)
{
     $user_id = $request->user_id
     if ($request->acticate) {
           $this->activateUser($user_id);
     }
     elseif ($request->inactiavte) {
           $this->deactivateUser($user_id);
     }
return redirect(route('admins-users.index'))->with('message-post', 'Status was updated successfully');
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: but in your route you specified post method. If you want to change it to get then you also have to change route method like this Route::get('..', '...');

Comment: the problems are how to get user id and activate it.

Comment: still not working, because you don't pass the value of status and user id when using method of activateUser and deactiveUser.

Comment: still not working. why are you use $request->activate. you don't pass it in views

Comment: In button you named activate/inactivate so if any button clicked then its value will be set, then in controller just we have to check that which button's value set/clicked.